# how to change this in python?(edges to vertex)

Tags: python

`[(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(3,5),(6,8),(10,1)]`
-> `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10]`

first line is edges in graph.

I want an array which contains different vertexes of the graph .

how to change this in python?

Comment: Can you explain how you got vertex list `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10]` ?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple approach:

```
>>> edges = [(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(3,5),(6,8),(10,1)]
>>> set().union(*edges)
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10}
```

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the already good answers, We can use `zip` function for unpacking lists

```
>>> l = [(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(3,5),(6,8),(10,1)] 
>>> list(set(zip(*l)[0]+zip(*l)[1]))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list1=[(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(3,5),(6,8),(10,1)]
list2=[]
for i in list1:
    for x in i:
        if x not in list2:
            list2.append(x)
print (list2)
```

Output:

```
>>> 
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x=[(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(3,5),(6,8),(10,1)]
z=list(set([k[0] for k in x]+[k[1] for k in x]))
```

You can try this.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> edges = np.array([(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(3,5),(6,8),(10,1)] )
>>> np.unique(edges)
array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  8, 10])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> sorted(set(itertools.chain.from_iterable([(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(3,5),(6,8),(10,1)])))
>>> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x = [(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(3,5),(6,8),(10,1)]
y = list(set(sum(x, ())))
```

Comment: y is the output ( [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10] )